# how to customise jquery bracket world plugins round wise

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on generating tournament brackets dynamically. I am using this plugin.

https://github.com/lipp15/bracket-world

which is working as expected. But the problem in this plugin is that we can set matches for first round only.
I'd done lots of google to find the solution of all round matches but i could not able to got it. Does anyone know how to show matches up to final rounds? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please guys help me i got stuck in this